# Invalid type error when trying to push source that contains the missing Type?

Tags: salesforcedx

I have a bunch of apex classes i am trying to push to my scratch org. I get an Invalid type error for a lot of my referenced classes that contained in the classes i am trying to push.

If i put one of the problematic classes in the forceignore fle, nothing seems to get pushed. It's almost as if the Type classes are being ignored/not pushed for some reason.

My forceignore looks like

```
package.xml
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json
```

Ie.

force-app

--main

----default

-------Classes

---------MyClass.cls

---------MyOtherClass.cls

**MyClass.cls**

```
public class MyClass {
    //fields
}
```

**MyOtherClass.cls**

```
public class MyOtherClass {
    MyClass class;
}
```

When i try to run

```
sfdx force:source:push --json --loglevel fatal --forceoverwrite
```

i get a compile error:

```
Invalid type: MyClass
```

Comment: Can you post what one of those classes look like and what throws an error?

Comment: @JayantDas what information would you need to know? They are fairly large classes. I'll post a generic example in the OP

Comment: Yeah, a generic example will work here which can provide as what lines are causing issues.

Comment: @JayantDas i added some more info

Comment: Is that the only error you see in console? Are there any other relevant message that could be helpful here?

Comment: Seconding @JayantDas; much of the time an error like this occurs as a downstream result of a completely different error (or its own downstream results!) blocking `MyClass` from being deployed.

Comment: @DavidReed here's the full push log. https://pastebin.com/mqbUKUz9 i would understand if it rejected Sf2EnTransformer because it has errors but i'm not sure why it is saying invalid type. The type it is trying to import is really just a Type class, no functions.